# Reading binary files in R

Tags: r

On the following code its possible to import part of the LAS files version 1.1 with those properties:

List. Item  Format  Size  Required

1. X  long  4 bytes  *
2. Y  long  4 bytes  *
3. Z  long  4 bytes  *
4. intensity  unsigned short  2 bytes
5. Return Number  3 bits (bits 0, 1, 2)  3 bits  *
6. Number of Returns (given pulse)  3 bits (bits 3, 4, 5)  3 bits  *
7. Scan Direction Flag  1 bit (bit 6)  1 bit  *
8. Edge of Flight Line  1 bit (bit 7)  1 bit  *
9. Classification  unsigned char  1 byte  *
10. Scan Angle Rank (-90 to +90) – Left side  unsigned char  1 byte  *
11. User Data  unsigned char  1 byte
12. Point Source ID  unsigned short  2 bytes  *
13. GPS Time  double  8 bytes  *

and return x, y, z and intensity (lines 1 to 4 of list above):

```
allbytes <- matrix(readBin(con, "raw", n = pointDataRecordLength * numberPointRecords, size = 1, endian = "little"),
                   ncol= pointDataRecordLength, nrow = numberPointRecords, byrow = TRUE)    
close(con)
mm <- matrix(readBin(t(allbytes[,1:(3*4)]), "integer", size = 4, n = 3 * numberPointRecords, endian = "little"), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

mm[,1] <- mm[ ,1] * xyzScaleOffset[1,1] + xyzScaleOffset[1, 2]
mm[,2] <- mm[ ,2] * xyzScaleOffset[2,1] + xyzScaleOffset[2, 2]
mm[,3] <- mm[ ,3] * xyzScaleOffset[3,1] + xyzScaleOffset[3, 2]
colnames(mm) <- c("x", "y", "z")

intensity <- readBin(t(allbytes[, 13:14]), "double", size = 2, n = numberPointRecords, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")
```

I would like to extend the code to read also the "return number" and the "number of return" (line 5 and 6 of table).  What i'm doing wrong?

```
returnNumber <- readBin(t(allbytes[, 15]), "integer", size = 1, n = numberPointRecords, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")
```

The expected return should be integers between 1 and 5. Thanks in advance!

Example file:

[link](http://www.filefactory.com/file/68sdgepk12pd/n/lidar_las)

full code:

```
    publicHeaderDescription <- function() {
  hd <- structure(list(Item = c("File Signature (\"LASF\")",
                                "(1.1) File Source ID", "(1.1) Global Encoding",
                                "(1.1) Project ID - GUID data 1", "(1.1) Project ID - GUID data 2",
                                "(1.1) Project ID - GUID data 3", "(1.1) Project ID - GUID data 4",
                                "Version Major", "Version Minor", "(1.1) System Identifier",
                                "Generating Software", "(1.1) File Creation Day of Year",
                                "(1.1) File Creation Year", "Header Size", "Offset to point data",
                                "Number of variable length records",
                                "Point Data Format ID (0-99 for spec)", "Point Data Record Length",
                                "Number of point records", "Number of points by return",
                                "X scale factor", "Y scale factor", "Z scale factor", "X offset",
                                "Y offset", "Z offset", "Max X", "Min X", "Max Y", "Min Y", "Max Z",
                                "Min Z"), Format = c("char[4]", "unsigned short", "unsigned short",
                                                     "unsigned long", "unsigned short", "unsigned short",
                                                     "unsigned char[8]", "unsigned char", "unsigned char", "char[32]",
                                                     "char[32]", "unsigned short", "unsigned short", "unsigned short",
                                                     "unsigned long", "unsigned long", "unsigned char", "unsigned short",
                                                     "unsigned long", "unsigned long[5]", "double", "double", "double",
                                                     "double", "double", "double", "double", "double", "double", "double",
                                                     "double", "double"), Size = c("4 bytes", "2 bytes", "2 bytes",
                                                                                   "4 bytes", "2 byte", "2 byte", "8 bytes", "1 byte", "1 byte",
                                                                                   "32 bytes", "32 bytes", "2 bytes", "2 bytes", "2 bytes", "4 bytes",
                                                                                   "4 bytes", "1 byte", "2 bytes", "4 bytes", "20 bytes", "8 bytes",
                                                                                   "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes",
                                                                                   "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes", "8 bytes"), Required =
                                                                                     c("*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*",
                                                                                       "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*",
                                                                                       "*", "*", "*", "*", "*")), .Names = c("Item", "Format", "Size",
                                                                                                                             "Required"), row.names = 2:33, class = "data.frame")
  hd$what <- ""
  hd$what[grep("unsigned", hd$Format)] <- "integer"
  hd$what[grep("char", hd$Format)] <- "raw"
  hd$what[grep("short", hd$Format)] <- "integer"
  hd$what[grep("long", hd$Format)] <- "integer"
  hd$what[grep("double", hd$Format)] <- "numeric"
  hd$signed <- TRUE
  hd$signed[grep("unsigned", hd$Format)] <- FALSE
  ## number of values in record
  hd$n <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:][:punct:]]", "", hd$Format))
  hd$n[hd$what == "character"] <- 1
  hd$n[is.na(hd$n)] <- 1
  ## size of record
  hd$Hsize <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", hd$Size))
  ## size of each value in record
  hd$Rsize <- hd$Hsize / hd$n
  hd$Rsize[hd$what == "raw"] <- 1
  hd$n[hd$what == "raw"] <- hd$Hsize[hd$what == "raw"]
  hd
}

readLAS <-
  function(lasfile, skip = 0, nrows = NULL, returnSP = FALSE, returnHeaderOnly = FALSE) {

    hd <- publicHeaderDescription()
    pheader <- vector("list", nrow(hd))
    names(pheader) <- hd$Item
    con <- file(lasfile, open = "rb")
    isLASFbytes <- readBin(con, "raw", size = 1, n = 4, endian = "little")
    pheader[[hd$Item[1]]] <- readBin(isLASFbytes, "character", size = 4, endian = "little")
    if (! pheader[[hd$Item[1]]] == "LASF") {
      stop("Not a valid LAS file")
    }
    for (i in 2:nrow(hd)) {
      pheader[[hd$Item[i]]] <- readBin(con, what = hd$what[i], signed = hd$signed[i], size = hd$Rsize[i], endian = "little", n = hd$n[i])
      #print(names(pheader)[i])
      #print(pheader[[hd$Item[i]]])
    }
    close(con)
    ## read the data
    numberPointRecords <- pheader[["Number of point records"]]
    offsetToPointData <- pheader[["Offset to point data"]]
    pointDataRecordLength <-pheader[["Point Data Record Length"]]
    xyzScaleOffset <- cbind(unlist(pheader[c("X scale factor", "Y scale factor", "Z scale factor")]),
                            unlist(pheader[c("X offset", "Y offset", "Z offset")]))


    if (returnHeaderOnly) return(pheader)

    con <- file(lasfile, open = "rb")
    junk <- readBin(con, "raw", size = 1, n = offsetToPointData)

    ## deal with rows to skip and max rows to be read
    if (skip > 0) {
      ## seek is unreliable on windows, or I'm using it incorrectly
      ## so we junk the bytes to skip
      junk <- readBin(con, "raw", size = 1, n = pointDataRecordLength * skip)
      numberPointRecords <- numberPointRecords - skip
      #pos <- seek(con, where = pointDataRecordLength * skip)
      # print(c(pos = seek(con), skip = skip, where = pointDataRecordLength * skip))
    }
    if (!is.null(nrows)) {
      if (numberPointRecords > nrows) numberPointRecords <- nrows
    }

    if (numberPointRecords < 1) stop("no records left to read")


    # include a loop to read just points inside the x and y coordinates

    allbytes <- matrix(readBin(con, "raw", n = pointDataRecordLength * numberPointRecords, size = 1, endian = "little"),
                       ncol= pointDataRecordLength, nrow = numberPointRecords, byrow = TRUE)


    close(con)
    mm <- matrix(readBin(t(allbytes[,1:(3*4)]), "integer", size = 4, n = 3 * numberPointRecords, endian = "little"), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
    gpstime <- NULL
    if (ncol(allbytes) == 28) gpstime <- readBin(t(allbytes[ , 21:28]), "numeric", size = 8, n = numberPointRecords, endian = "little")

    intensity <- readBin(t(allbytes[, 13:14]), "double", size = 2, n = numberPointRecords, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")
    mm[,1] <- mm[ ,1] * xyzScaleOffset[1,1] + xyzScaleOffset[1, 2]
    mm[,2] <- mm[ ,2] * xyzScaleOffset[2,1] + xyzScaleOffset[2, 2]
    mm[,3] <- mm[ ,3] * xyzScaleOffset[3,1] + xyzScaleOffset[3, 2]
    colnames(mm) <- c("x", "y", "z")

    returnNumber <- readBin(t(allbytes[,15]), "integer", size = 1, n = numberPointRecords, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")
    require(bitops)


    if (returnSP) {
      require(sp)
      SpatialPoints(cbind(mm, gpstime, intensity))
    } else {
      cbind(mm, gpstime, intensity)
    }
  }
```

Comment: An example of what you get in returnNumber might help.

Comment: @themel, I'm getting this: **0 0 32 0 0 63 204 65 0 0 ...** but I was expecting something like ** 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 ...**. The return number should be 1 2 or 3.

Comment: @themel, I think now the link to my file is ok. I moved to another host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from your question that you understand that fields 5-8 are all encoded in a single byte, so you'll need to extract the bits. Assuming the rest of your code works,

```
require(bitops)

fields.5.to.8 <- readBin(t(allbytes[, 15]), "integer", size = 1, n = numberPointRecords, signed = FALSE, endian = "little")

# bits 0..2: byte & 00000111
field.5 <- bitAnd(7, fields.5.to.8)
# bits 3..5: byte & 00111000 >> 3
field.6 <- bitShiftR(bitAnd(56, fields.5.to.8), 3)
# bit 6: & 0100000 >> 6
field.7 <- bitShiftR(bitAnd(fields.5.to.8, 64), 6)
# bit 7: & 1000000 >> 7 
field.8 <- bitShiftR(bitAnd(fields.5.to.8, 128), 7)
```

Comment: thanks! You are right 5-8 items are all inside the same byte! And that is exactly my difficult... how to read this... your code returned: **0 0 0 0 0 7 4 1 0 0 ...**, but I was expecting just integer values between 1 and 3.

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling to make sense of the test data you provided as well. As far as I understand, my answer does what you state in the comment. Of course, we don't really know whether by "bit 0" they mean "most significant bit" or "least significant bit", but neither of those interpretations gave me sensible results with the test data you posted.

Comment: I would like to interpret: always that bit 0 = 1, 'return number' = 1. Always that bit 1 = 1, 'return number' = 2 and always bit 3 = 1, 'return number' = 3.

Comment: Sorry, its quite difficult to explain because interpret binary file is quite new for me. But the explanations of binary file i'm using is provided by ASPRS under http://www.asprs.org/a/society/committees/standards/asprs_las_format_v11.pdf.

Comment: Do you think that my interpret of bit make sense?

Comment: Err, no, my answer doesn't do what you say in your comment, but I'm pretty sure that that is also not what the spec says. I'm a bit suspicious about your test data since you have zeroes in there and the spec states that the return number should be between 0 and 5. Maybe the way you get to the bytes is already off?

Comment: Maybe I should look as binary also... like 001 in 0to2 bits >> 'return number' = 1. 010 >> 'return number' = 2. 011 >> 'return number' = 3. 100 >> 'return number' = 4 and 101 >> 'return number' = 5. The same idea to Number of return, but now analyzing bits 3 to 5. What do you think? Is it possible no implement that?

Comment: Yeah... you are right... something should be wrong in the code. For x, y and z the results are consistent. :(

Comment: Code in my answer does more or less what your second-to-last comment implements. If you post a fully reproducible example (i.e. runnable code + sample data) that would save us guesswork.

Comment: Tried your code with this sample file: http://www.liblas.org/samples/format_permutations/las11_format0.las - returnNumber from that file has no zeroes and parses fine with the code from my answer. Maybe it's your file? (can't get at the yousendit file cause it wants me to provide an email address I can't guess).

Comment: Really? Afff. I used yousendit so time ago... I think they are not any more sharing files for free. :) Thanks @themel!

Comment: Code: https://gist.github.com/3911799, run on your file, using R 2.15.0: https://gist.github.com/3911828 (I had to change your "intensity" read since it would not run on my R, but the rest of your code is unchanged)