# Reading binary file into R

Tags: r, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a binary file into R but this file has rows of data written in binary code. So it doesnt have one full set of data belonging to one column instead it is stored as rows of data. Here's what my data looks like:

```
Bytes 1-4:            int        ID
Byte 5:               char       response character
Bytes 6-9:            int        Resp Dollars
Byte 10:              char       Type char
```

Anyone can help me figure out how to read this file into R?

Here is the code I have tried so far. I tried a couple of things with limited success. Unfortunately, I cant post any of the data on public sites, apologies. I’m relatively new to R, so I need some help in terms of how to improve the code.

```
> binfile = file("File Location", "rb")
> IDvals = readBin(binfile, integer(), size=4, endian = "little")
> Responsevals = readBin(binfile, character (), size = 5)
> ResponseDollarsvals = readBin (binfile, integer (), size = 9, endian= "little")
Error in readBin(binfile, integer(), size = 9, endian = "little") : 
  size 9 is unknown on this machine
> Typevals = readBin (binfile, character (), size=4)
> binfile1= cbind(IDvals, Responsevals, ResponseDollarsvals, Typevals)
> dimnames(binfile1)[[2]]
[1] "IDvals"            "Responsevals"        "ResponseDollarsvals" "Typevals"  

> colnames(binfile1)=binfile
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 4L) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the data file?

Comment: Read it as raw bytes with readBin, push that into a matrix with nrows same as file, then readBin from sets of columns. It's fast. This does essentially that for a more complicated format, drop all the header stuff and slurp away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931979/reading-binary-files-in-r

Comment: Provide the file and I'll put together an example.

Comment: mdsumner - I cant share the data file because of company NDA agreements - is there any way you can post the simplified version of the code? I'm relatively new to R so am having some difficulty following the code in the link you posted....thANKS!

Comment: the thing I can't be bothered doing is generating a test file, and that's what's wrong with your question

Answer (score 7):

You could open the file as a raw file, then issue readBin or readChar commands to get each line.  Append each value to a column as you go.

```
my.file <- file('path', 'rb')

id <- integer(0)
response <- character(0)
...
```

Loop around this block:

```
id = c(id, readBin(my.file, integer(), size = 4, endian = 'little'))
response = c(response, readChar(my.file, 1))
...
readChar(my.file, size = 1) # For UNIX newlines.  Use size = 2 for Windows newlines.
```

Then create your data frame.

See here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/read_binary.htm

Comment: Hi Matthew - I'm trying to follow your code but am wondering how I would determine if my file has UNIX or Windows newlines? Thanks!

Comment: That's something that you'll have to know, based on how you wrote the file.  You can determine by looking at the binary data.  If you're on a UNIX system, the command 'od -t x1 <file>' will print the byte values.  A single '0a' as a line terminator means UNIX line endings.  A pair, '0d' and '0a' mean Windows line endings.  No space between one record and the next mean no line endings, and you should not use the extra readChar() call to suck up the (non-existing) ending characters.

Comment: Matthew - I figured out the windows line endings - one last question - im trying to figure out the correct byte size to input for my response dollars column - every time i try to input byte size - I keep getting an error saying that the size is unknown on this machine - ive tried the following byte sizes - 6,9,3,4,5 - thanks in advance for your help