# Using readbin() in R

Tags: r, binary

In [Reading Binary files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354113/reading-binary-file-into-r)

Seth wrote: "Read it as raw bytes with readBin, push that into a matrix with nrows same as file, then readBin from sets of columns. It's fast."

I am new enough to R and binary files to not know how to do what he is saying.

I have a file written from Fortran (sorry I don't know the version). The OS (Windows 7, Service Pack 1) says that the file is 11,962 KB. I am told that the record length is 160 bytes.

How would I read that file into a matrix with nrows same as file?

John Orr

Comment: You need to know more about the structure of each record.  Those 160 bytes might be 4 byte integers, 8 byte integers, 4 byte floats, 8 byte floats, 10 byte floats, etc.  You need to know that before you can read it.  You can guess (e.g. all 8 byte floats, 1st record readable by `readBin("file", "numeric", n = 160/8, size = 8)` but even if it looks like it might be right, you'll never be sure.

Comment: Andrie, thanks for commenting. I used your snippet and still am not getting the expected values. Question: what are you saying in "n = 160/8"? I would've thought that the maximum number of records should be 11,962/160.

Comment: Andrie, thanks for commenting. You suggested that I needed to know more about the structure of each record so I investigated the docmentation online and found that I may have been using an incomplete or outdated source for documentation. Thanks for getting me off dead center (hopefully).