# What is the n parameter in readBin() R

Tags: r, byte

I'm trying to translate some `R` code that uses the `readBin()` to decode a file.
However, I don't understand the meaning of the `n` parameter in this function.

It is described in the [documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/3.2.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/base/readBin.html) as

> an integer specifying the maximum number of values to read

but what does this actually mean ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this TIBCO documentation you're referring to, but if you look at the [official](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/readBin) one which you call with `?readBin`, the explanation is a bit more detailed, including the examples. So maybe that can help you understand the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?readBin`, the return object is

> [...] a vector of appropriate mode and length the number
>        of items read (which might be less than ‘n’).

So `n` does exactly what it says: It sets an (upper) limit on the number of values it reads; also note that

> [y]ou can use an over-estimate here, but not too large as storage is reserved for ‘n’ items.

Also see:

1. [Using `readbin` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414581/using-readbin-in-r).
2. [Reading binary file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354113/reading-binary-file-into-r)